# In Type-1 hypervisor architecture, how are calls to hardware made?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, hypervisor

When using a type-1 hypervisor, I want to understand few things better.

Does the hypervisor give direct control of the requested hardware to the guest?

Things like allocation of number of CPU cores, memory etc.

Or does the hypervisor sit between the guest/virtual OS and hardware and take the responsibility of translating the call to underlying hardware?

Answer (score 1):

#### What is the difference between a Type-1 and a Type-2 hypervisor.

> Does a type 1 hypervisor give direct control of the requested hardware to the guest?

Yes:

> **Type-1, native or bare-metal hypervisors**
>
> These hypervisors run directly on the host's hardware to control the
> hardware and to manage guest operating systems. For this reason, they
> are sometimes called bare metal hypervisors.

Or

> Does the hypervisor sit between the guest/virtual OS and hardware and take the responsibility of translating the call to underlying hardware?

That is what a Type-2 hypervisor does:

> **Type-2 or hosted hypervisors**
>
> These hypervisors run on a conventional operating system (OS) just as
> other computer programs do. A guest operating system runs as a process
> on the host. Type-2 hypervisors abstract guest operating systems from
> the host operating system.

Source [Hypervisor - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypervisor)

Comment: No. Read the answer again. What your are describing in your comment is type-2

Comment: thanks for clarification, your edit clarifies it.